# Java - Problem with Latin characters in thermal printer

Tags: java, thermal-printer

I have a text printer which prints without any problem, but it does not print Latin characters, I have tried changing the CharsetCode, printing from a pdf and it does not work with Latin characters
This is my code currently

```
public static boolean print(String text,String printer){
    DocFlavor docFormat = DocFlavor.BYTE_ARRAY.AUTOSENSE;
    PrintService defaultPrintService = getPrinter(printer);
    DocPrintJob printJob = defaultPrintService.createPrintJob();
    try {
        byte[] bytes = text.getBytes("utf-8");
        Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(bytes, docFormat, null);
        System.out.println(doc.getPrintData());
        System.out.println("drag");
        printJob.print(doc, null);
    }catch (Exception ee) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;   
}
```

Comment: what are "latin characters" (really the latin alphabet a-z)? `text.getBytes("utf-8");` might be the issue but finding the right kind of character encoding could be tricky if there's no information what the printer / API accepts.

Comment: If you've got a string, then why not ```DocFlavor.STRING``` ?

Comment: How well do non-java applications work with the printer?  Could you, for example,  enter something into a text editor, and print that?

Comment: Make and model number please